# Multiple Variable Conditions for If Statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, logic

Thanks for the help in this, I think i have over complicated the below but the logic just isn't responding how my mind is telling it too.

Logic in Question:

```
$a = "One"
$b = "Two"
$c = "Three"
$d = "Four"

If( {$a -and $b} -ne {$c and $d} ) {
   Write-Host "Values are Different"
} Else {
   Write-Host "values are the same"
}
```

I want the If statement to run when $a and $b are different to $c and $d, If the are the same see below, I want it to output that the values are the same

```
$a = "One"
$b = "One"
$c = "One"
$d = "One"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to compare the value pairs as arrays**:

```
if (Compare-Object $a, $b   $c, $d  -SyncWindow 0) {
  'different'
} else {
  'same'
}
```

Note that this is convenient, but relatively slow, which may matter in a loop with many iterations.

- The [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) compares two arrays and by default returns information about their differences.
- `-SyncWindow 0` compares only directly corresponding array elements; in other words: `$a` must equal `$c`, and `$b` must equal `$d`; without `-SyncWindow`, the array elements would be compared in any order so that `1, 2` would be considered equal to `2, 1` for instance.
- Using the `Compare-Object` call's result as a conditional implicitly coerces the result to a Boolean, and any *nonempty* result - indicating the presence of at least 1 difference - will evaluate to `$True`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Use of `{ ... }` in your conditional is not appropriate.
Expressions enclosed in `{ ... }` are *script blocks* - pieces of code you can execute later, such as with `&` or `.`

Even if you used `(...)` instead to clarify operator precedence (`-ne` has higher precedence than 
`-and`), your conditional wouldn't work as expected, however:

- `($a -and $b) -ne ($c -and $d)` treats all variables as *Booleans*; in effect, given PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion, you're comparing whether one value pair has at least one *empty string* to whether the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) and avoiding the rather slow [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object):

In **what you tried**, you will need to compare one specific value with each of the rest of the vales:

```
($a -eq $b) -and ($a -eq $c) -and ($a -eq $d)
```

Because the [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) (`-eq`) take a [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-6) than the [Logical Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-6) (`-and`), you can leave the brackets and simplify it to:

```
$a -eq $b -and $a -eq $c -and $a -eq $d
```

To make this code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and easily expandable for even more values:

```
if ($a, $b, $c | Where {$_ -ne $d}) {
  'different'
} else {
  'same'
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just remove these `{}` brackets from the if statement

```
   $a = "One"
    $b = "One"
    $c = "One"
    $d = "One"

    If($a -and $b -ne $c -and $d) {
       Write-Host "Values are Different"
    } Else {
       Write-Host "values are the same"
    }
```

Comment: Due to operator precedence, your conditional is the same as `$a -and ($b -ne $c) -and $d`, but even with precedence clarified with `(...)` the logic won't work as intended. You are correct about the `{...}` being inappropriate, however.

Comment: @mklement0 `if (($a -and $b) -ne ($c -and $d)) { ... }` would clarify the precedence?

Comment: @Jelphy: It would clarify the precedence, but it doesn't do what the OP wants (see my answer for what it actually does).